# A problem about quadrilateral inscribed in circle divide the segment.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Quadrilateral ABCD is inscribed in circle O.

AB and DC intersects at point E, AD and BC intersect at point F.

The area of traingle ABC ,traingle ADC are equal, prove that EH = HF.

---

I wonder whether this problem can be solved by pencil of conics that pass A,B,C,D.

Which I suppose EF is the X-axis, then EH , FH can be the two root of the formula.

I don't know how to take advantage of the given condition that the area of triangles are equal.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks:)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Quadrilateral ABCD]

If we denote the intersection point of $BD$ and $AC$ by $L$, then $L$ will be the midpoint of $BD$.

Then, $\frac{BC}{AD}=\frac{CL}{LD}=\frac{CL}{BL}=\frac{CD}{AB}$

$\triangle EBC\sim \triangle EDA$

$\Rightarrow  \frac{CE}{AE}=\frac{BC}{AD}$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{CE}{AE}=\frac{CD}{AB}$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{CE}{CD}=\frac{AE}{AB}$

Applying Menelaus' Theorem on $\triangle AED$ considering $BCF$ as the transversal gives,

$\frac{AB}{BE}\cdot \frac{EC}{CD}\cdot \frac{DF}{AF}=1$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{AB}{BE}\cdot \frac{AE}{AB}\cdot \frac{DF}{AF}=1$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{AE}{BE}=\frac{AF}{DF}$

Hence, $BD\parallel EF$.

Since $AC$ bisects $BD$, $AC$ must bisect $EF$ as well. Thus, $H$ is the midpoint of $EF$.